# bat file to replace the name of a folder and toggle between two databases

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, rename

I would like to create a very simple batch script to toggle the name of 2 folders with a click on a button. (I am reusing the same windows app with two different databases in two different folders)

For some reason, this batch file does not work

```
:: myrename.bat
@echo off

IF EXIST C:\win_cgs MOVE C:\win win_palm & MOVE C:\win_cgs win & goto endofscript
IF NOT EXIST C:\win_cgs MOVE C:\win win_cgs & MOVE C:\win_palm win

:endofscript
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
:: myrename.bat
@echo off &setlocal
cd /d C:\
IF EXIST C:\win_cgs MOVE C:\win win_palm & MOVE C:\win_cgs win & goto endofscript
IF NOT EXIST C:\win_cgs MOVE C:\win win_cgs & MOVE C:\win_palm win

:endofscript
```